# XML + Schema + Namespaces. No matching global declaration available for the validation root

Tags: xml, namespaces, schema

What is the correct syntax when referring to schema when using namespaces?

**Problem**

Creating an XML document using a given schema.

**Error**

```
    .xml:9.20: Element '{http://example/buildings/1.0}old_buildings': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
    oldbuildings.xml - invalid
    Problem
```

**XML Document**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<buildings:old_buildings xmlns:buildings="http://example/buildings/1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://example/buildings/1.0 oldbuildings_schema.xsd">
    <building>
        <name>Name</name>
        <year_built era="BC">2000</year_built>
        <story>...<story>
    </building>
</buildings:old_buildings>
```

**XSD Document**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://example/buildings/1.0/" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns="http://example/buildings/1.0/">
        <xs:element name="old_buildings">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="building"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="building" type="buildingType"></xs:element>


        <xs:complexType name="buildingType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="year_built" type="yearType"/>
                <xs:element name="story" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="yearType">
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:positiveInteger">
                    <xs:attribute name="era" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your xml file, try with

> xmlns:buildings="http://example/buildings/1.0/"

with a / final, as in your xsd declaration : `xs:schema targetNamespace="http://example/buildings/1.0/"`

Comment: @BurhanAli because the URI needs to match in both, the schema and the XML file. "/" was missing in one of the URIs.

Answer (score 1):

From xml document
Missing closing tag

```
 <story>...<story>
```

To

```
<story>...</story>
```